# JavaScript parameter dependent class inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I have the following classes hierarchy:

```
  Renderer (can render some data on screen)
     |
 DbRenderer (fetch data from the database)
     |
JsonRenderer (my class. converts specific data into needed format supported by Renderer)
```

It works well but requires to pass DB connection parameters into JsonRenderer constructor in order to call constructor() of DbRenderer via super() since this parameter is obligatory there.

So, it looks like:

```
const renderer = new JsonRenderer(dbParams);
```

, where

```
class JsonRenderer extends DbRenderer {}
```

But, I want to make dbParams optional and change classes hierarchy to the following:

```
   Renderer
      |
  JsonRenderer
```

I can do it by creating separate class:

```
class JsonRenderer2 extends Renderer {}
```

Off course separate class will be a source of code duplication and this is not a good idea.

Is there some solution for my situation without changing of Renderer and DbRenderer parent classes?

Comment: `JsonRenderer` should not be a child of `DbRenderer` if it is not a `DbRenderer`. Overall it seems strange to be that `DbRenderer` extends `Renderer` in the first place. Does it actually render anything or is it more of a data source that other renderers can use? Maybe a different model is more suitable for your universe.

Comment: `DbRenderer` just fetch some data. `JsonRenderer` know how this data can be converted and passed into `Renderer` to show on screen.

Comment: `DbRenderer` shouldn't extend `Renderer` then. Seems like it should be passed as a data source to `JsonRenderer`. In general, class inheritance should only be used for *is-a* relationships. E.g. a dog *is an* animal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misuse the inheritance here. It is hard to tell for sure without knowing more about what each class does, but I feel like you can have the following structure instead:

```
       Renderer (can render some data on screen, 
                 uses DataSource class instance 
                 to get the data to display)

       DataSource
      /          \
     /            \
    /              \
 DbData            JsonData
(fetch data        (uses data from JSON)
from the database)
```

Having this structure, you can either do `renderer = new JsonRenderer(DbData(dbParams))` or `renderer = new JsonRenderer(JsonData(data))`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did - created separate JsonDataProvider class and in constructor of JsonRenderer select which dataProvider to use depending on provided dbParams or JSON data